# Unusual stringWithFormat: argument

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, mapkit

I apologize if this is a noob question.

I have been following [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/21365/introduction-to-mapkit-in-ios-6-tutorial) tutorial about mapkit and I stumbled on this line of code

```
NSString *json = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString,
                      centerLocation.latitude,
                      centerLocation.longitude,
                      0.5 * METERS_PER_MILE];
```

The reason this is unusual at least to me is that it is missing the nsstring that has the %@ flags in it.  The tutorial claims that we are adding the latitude and longitude information into the json.

But when I print out formatString and json, the output is identical.

I have never seen nsstrings used in this way before.  Is there a hidden variable that is getting set?

Can someone explain to me how this nsstring object (named json) contains those 4 arguments?

Answer (score 2):

Someplace else in the code, formatString must be defined something like this:

```
NSString *formatString = @"latitude=%f, longitude=%f, %f = half the number of meters in a mile";
```

Make sure your test looks like this:

```
NSLog(@"the format is %@ and the json is %@", formatString, json);
```

They shouldn't look the same.  The only way they would look the same is if format string doesn't refer to any format specifiers, like this:

```
NSString *formatString = @"I'm a silly format with no percent format specifiers";
```

[Here's a good intro on the topic](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) from Apple.

Answer (score 1):

That `formatString` actually contains the `%@`'s. It might be like this:

```
NSString *formatString = @"lat: %f | lon: %f | half-meters-per-mile: %f";

NSString *json = [NSString stringWithFormat:formatString,
                  centerLocation.latitude,
                  centerLocation.longitude,
                  0.5 * METERS_PER_MILE];
```

(note that the substitutions (`%f`) might not be correct, I'm guessing)

As for how it contains those four arguments, everything after the first one are values that you want added into the string. The first one is a string that says where to put those values.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the tutorial, following line of code is written above what you have posted-

```
 NSString *jsonFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"command" ofType:@"json"];
 NSString *formatString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsonFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
```

From here the format string is created, this file will be available in the resources folder of your tutorial.